# Request Wait Time/Time to First Byte

Tags: iis, iis-7, performancecounter, response-time

While working on performance improvement, I came across situation where

1. Application logs giving X time to execute all the steps(using Stopwatch)
2. IIS logs, which also suggest X time-taken for that request.
3. But our client another API, which is sending that request logs a time which is X+Y. Where Y is really big.

What I suspect is that for Y times that request was waiting in IIS queue or in ASP.NET Queue.

So I want that data. Which request waited how much time in the queue?

I came across a Performance Counter "Request Wait Time" but this only gives the wait time for the last served request.

Any suggestion on how to monitor request for this metric?

Comment: in my opinion, there is no tool or logs to log request wait time for each particular request. but you can see the request waiting time on browser developer tool [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4XSX.png).

Comment: Yeah... Me too unable to find any convenient tool for this.